# Unable to tap into the mongo shell using the "mongo" command

Tags: mongodb

Seeing this message when I hit the "mongo" command on the terminal :

"/c/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/bin/mongo.exe: No such file or directory"

It is true that mongo.exe is not present at that location. But MongoDB version 6.0 and newer apparently do not have the legacy mongo.exe file. So, in spite of a successful installation, I do not have a mongo.exe file.

In such a case, how do I tap into the shell ? Please note that the commands "mongos" and "mongosh" are not working (command not found). mongos.exe is present at the location (/c/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/bin) though.

Answer (score -1):

Yes MongoDB version 6.0 and above don't have mongo.exe file. Command is `mongod`. After installing msi file you need to install MongoDB Shell . Go through this link which have step by step guide to install MongoDB.
https://hevodata.com/learn/windows-mongodb-shell/